# Structuring display with indent JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nested, indentation

I have input object that looks like this:

```
 myObj = {
        "Ob1": {
            "myObjName": "A1",
            "myObjType": "string",
            "myObjOcc": "minOccurs="1""
            "Ob2": {
                "myObjName": "B1",
                "myObjType": "string",
                "myObjOcc": "minOccurs="1""
                "Ob3": {
                    "myObjName": "C1",
                    "myObjType": "string",
                    "myObjOcc": "minOccurs="1""
                } 
            }
         }
         "Ob4": {
                    "myObjName": "A2",
                    "myObjType": "string",
                    "myObjOcc": "minOccurs="1""
         }
    }
```

And I have to display the objects in xml schema way:

```
<xs:complexType name="A1" type="string" minOccurs="1">
   <xs:complexType name="B1" type="string" minOccurs="1">
      <xs:simpleType name="C1" type="string" minOccurs="1"/>
   </complexType>
</complexType>
<xs:simpleType name="A2" type="string" minOccurs="1"/>
```

The idea is, if an object has child is a complexType if not, it's simpleType.

I have this code that is doing the printing, but if anyone can help me structure it with indent:

```
    function isNestedObject(obj) {
        for (var o in obj) {
            if (isComplexType(o, obj)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    function isComplexType(key, obj) {
        return (typeof obj[key] === "object");
    }

    function xsdStructure(obj) {
        var str = "",
            properties = obj.properties;              

        if (isNestedObject(obj)) {
            if (obj instanceof Array) {
                for(var o in obj) {
                    xsdStructure(obj[o]);
                }
            }
            str += "<xs:complexType name=\"" + obj.attrName + "\" type=\"" + obj.type + "\" " + obj.multiplicty + ">\n";
            for (var key in obj) {
                var arr = obj[key];
                if (arr instanceof Array) {
                    for (var a in arr) {
                        str += xsdStructure(arr[a]);
                    }
                }
            } 
            str += "</xs:complexType>\n"
        } else {
            str = "<xs:simpleType name=\"" + obj.attrName + "\" type=\"" + obj.type + "\" " + obj.multiplicty + "/>\n";
        }

        return str;
     }

     function printing(myObj) {
        var result = "";
        for (var key in object) {
            result += xsdStructure(object[key]);
        }
        result = '<xs:schema>\n' 
                        + result 
                    + '</xs:schema>';

        return result;
     }
```

It suppose to look like the above xml schema, but I can't use DOMParser so it has to be done manually.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I prepared [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dganenco/hp98eb0c/) for you. I had few things to mention for you. First, you should use the same attrs names among all you function which works with initial object. Ex:  `str += "<xs:complexType name=\"" + obj.myObjName + "\" type=\"" + obj.myObjType + "\" " + obj.myObjOcc + ">\n";` and NOT your `str += "<xs:complexType name=\"" + obj.attrName + "\" type=\"" + obj.type + "\" " + obj.multiplicty + ">\n";` Also you will never get this condition true `if (obj instanceof Array)` because your obj doesn't contains arrays at all.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I don't see any changes in the structure from before when I run the fiddle.

Comment: Here new fiddle with updated function for pretty print https://jsfiddle.net/Dganenco/78fxrtqw/

Comment: Is it working for you? Because for me not! It's still the same result and you pass just one parameter to "formatXml" function

Comment: if you are using my 'pre' implementation you will never see result. It was added only for initial visualisation. Try in console and you will see correct result